# tablesorter ajax paging with results in html format

Tags: jquery, ajax, database

I have tablesorter working with ajax and it loads when a button is pushed and refreshes the table.  But I have 300-500 records for the table and want to be able to use paging, but also cut down on the load time and only load 25 or so records and then let the paging automatically pull in the rest when the user wants. I want to keep sorting and filtering on the table also.

I have seen some examples of this on tablesorter for using json and setting the header and rows with data, but i need to use html and send back records full of markup.
I have read a bunch of posts already and cant find the answer.  I am sending the records back in a json format but they are html based.
here is a sample of one of the records that is being sent back

```
{"selectedRows":" <tr>
<td class='someclass' >Norway Corp<br></td>
<td class='class2 colorbox currcol' id='3-1-2013-47-2974'> <a href='opendetail.asp'>2974</a></td> 
</tr>
}
```

any examples would be great.  I'm not sure where to go from here.  Or if there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

What if you just integrate a plug-in? It is easy to manage and very helpful. Check it out @ http://datatables.net/

Comment: thanks for the reply.  the "tablesorter" is a plug in.  I don't think i can use both at the same time.  i have looked at datatables but chose tablesort because of the implementation.